# "Un formulario en esta página tiene más de 10000 campos" ¿Qué puede suponer esto?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Me sale un mensaje emergente en phpMyAdmin al abrir la tabla de usuarios. Antes nunca me salía. ¿Qué sucede?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Un saludo.

Comment: Como bien dice @Pedro,  estás intentando ver demasiadas filas a la vez (500) según la imagen que muestras. Pero, como indica la advertencia, tu `max_input_vars` está establecido a `10,000` campos, esa cantidad en el caso de PHPMyAdmin se calcula multiplicando el número de filas por por el número de columnas. Eso quiere decir que, si tu tabla tiene `20` o más columnas e intentas mostrar `500` filas a la vez, te pasas del máximo permitido. Puedes aumentar el valor (no recomendado, nunca es factible trabajar con 10,000 datos en pantalla) o mostrar menos filas a la vez.

Comment: Cierto, a veces le doy a lo de ver 500, y claro, supongo que no conviene. Un saludo y gracias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que te sucede es que estás abriendo una tabla en la cual por primera vez el número de columnas de la tabla multiplicado por el número de filas supera el valor max_inputs_vars de la configuración de php que por defecto es 1.000. Eso sucede en PhpMyAdmin porque como casi todos los valores son editables "al vuelo", cada celda editable implica un campo de formulario.

Comment: ¿Me va a suponer un problema eso? ¿O es símplemente informativo? Gracias!

Comment: De acuerdo a la documentación de php [http://php.net/manual/es/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars]  lo esperable es que el script que procesa los datos trunque las variables que sobrepasan el límite máximo configurado en max_inputs_vars, de todas formas no se si esto representa un problema real, habría que revisar el código de PhpMyAdmin, pero dudo que se envíe un formulario con tantas variables en ocasión de uso.